# github how to remove merges that I already made into staging

Tags: git, github

I do not have much experience in handling git or github repository. This is only my second project I am using it in and suddenly ran into a problem. So I request not to downvote although it might look a stupid question.

I have two local branches off master which I pushed to github remote repository and merged those into staging. Everything was working fine before I accidentally merged staging into one of my branches!

Is there any way to discard all merges I did recently into staging and start over with new branches? Is this a good idea to remove my own branches from the github repository and push the new ones and then merge them again to staging?

I do not know the proper solution. If someone please suggest me the best way to do it, that will definitely save my life. I need to deploy staging into master today!

Comment: What is staging ? Post a gitk screenshot please showing what you did - issue `gitk --all`

Answer (score 0):

If the work of merging, etc was done on your machine, then you might be able to use `git reflog` to get an idea of individual commit SHAs that held the history. You can then checkout the branch to the specific SHA that you want, and force-push to the remote. This would "wipe out" the newer merge commits/changes.

For more info on `reflog`, see here: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest these steps to Fix the last commit

Scenario: You just typo'd the last commit message, you did git commit -m "Fxies bug #42" but before git push, you realized that really should say "Fixes bug #42".

Undo with: git commit --amend or git commit --amend -m "Fixes bug #42"

What's happening: git commit --amend will update and replace the most recent commit with a new commit that combines any staged changes with the contents of the previous commit. With nothing currently staged, this just rewrites the previous commit message.

For more information please read

https://github.com/blog/2019-how-to-undo-almost-anything-with-git

Comment: I don't think you realized my problem! Is not about amending commit message.